# vs code quick fix only shows spelling instead of create function

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes when I want to create new function derived from parameters I passed, the quick fix in vs studio doesn't give me that option. Instead it gives me an option to change spelling, despite clearly changing spelling will actually not work.

[image]

I'd like to be able to have 'Add Missing Function' option here. But it doesn't give me that. It's just trying to be too smart here. Is there a way to remove the spelling option all together and always allow me to create the new function?

Comment: I offer you to use github copilot, it's the best, please check it

Comment: Quick Fixes and all code intelligence features in general are provided by many different extensions, either built-in or third-party, most of them specialised in a single programming language or stack. If you're missing "Create Function" because you used to have it, please edit question body and question tags. If you are looking for an extension recommendation, I'm afraid that type of question is explicitly disallowed by Stack Overflow guidelines.